# Spring app share component over common interface into another app

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, servlets, interface, microservices

These projects runs on Tomcat server.

**Project Structure:** (contains following 3 projects)

- **shared** - (contains common interfaces) - This is not a Spring app
- **toolkit** - Main project (dependency to project shared) - Spring boot
- **service** - sub project (use project shared to get dao from toolkit) - Spring boot

**shared**

```
    public interface ConfigParamDAOnew {

    public static final String CLASS_NAME = "paramDAO";

    String getParamValueByName(String name);

}
```

**toolkit**

```
@Component
public class ParamModel_Global_DAO_Impl implements ConfigParamDAOnew {

    @Autowired
    ParamModel_GlobalJPARepository jpa;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public String getParamValueByName(String name) {
        return jpa.findByName(name).get().getValue();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        context.setAttribute(ConfigParamDAOnew.CLASS_NAME, this);
    }

}
```

**service**

```
@Service
public class NewConfigParamDAO {

    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    ConfigParamDAOnew dao;  

    public NewConfigParam getParam(String name) {
        loadConfigParamDAO();
        return new NewConfigParam(name, dao.getParamValueByName(name));            
    }

    private void loadConfigParamDAO() {
        dao = (ConfigParamDAOnew) 
        servletContext.getAttribute(ConfigParamDAOnew.CLASS_NAME);
    }
```

> ```
> > Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
> > de.usu.si.toolkit.config.NewConfigParamDAO.getParam(NewConfigParamDAO.java:35)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135)
> >     ... 27 more
> ```

The initial boot fails, after it is asked for dao from  toolkit project. This works to me before where can be mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured because bean NewConfigParamDAO was created before bean ParamModel_Global_DAO_Impl then that bean can not be found in ServletContext.

I fix this by annotation @DependsOn("paramModel_Global_DAO_Impl") in NewConfigParamDAO